# std::condition_variable::notify_one() called twice

Tags: c++, c++11, condition-variable

How many waiting threads will wake up if I call std::condition_variable::notify_one() twice without any time interval, like this:

```
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(condvar_mutex);

    condvar.notify_one();
    condvar.notify_one();
}
```

Is there any guarantee that these notifications will be delivered to different threads, not the same thread several times?

Comment: You are basically asking whether a notified thread (and locked on mutex) can be notified once more as it's not waiting anymore on the `cond_var` and is rather blocked on a `condvar_mutex`?

Comment: Sorry. This question was too unclear.
I've rephrased it here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085823/stdcondition-variablenotify-one-called-several-times-without-context-switc and flagged for remove.

Answer (score 4):

> §30.5.1.7: If any threads are blocked waiting for *this, unblocks one
>   of those threads.

There is no guarantee that it's different threads, just that it's **one** thread. During the time between the two `notify_one` calls it is possible that the same thread that was waked with the first `notify_one` is re-blocked.

e.g. In the following example it is not guaranteed whether thread 3 will wake or not (disregard spurious wakes for this example).

```
- thread 1:

1    condvar.notify_one();
- 3 and 4 could run here.
2    condvar.notify_one();

- thread 2:

3    condvar.wait(/*...*/);
4    condvar.wait(/*...*/);

- thread 3:

5    condvar.wait(/*...*/);
```

Comment: What will happen if I place both notify_one() under the same mutex to prevent your scenario?

Comment: Maybe I've asked the wrong question. In fact, I was wondering - is there any possibility to wake up just one condvar.wait(...) after calling notify_one() twice. So, let's suppose there is no 'thread 3' in your example. Is it possible that second thread will be notified only once and will be blocked in the second condvar.wait()?

Comment: It's not possible that the same thread that was woken up with the first call get re-blocked. In fact, it's not even possible that any thread is woken up after the first notify.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `condvar_mutex` is the correct mutex for the condvar.

It's not possible for both notifications to be delivered to the same thread. The reason is that you call `notify_one` twice *while holding the mutex*. So whichever thread is unblocked first, there's no way it can acquire the mutex, so it can't return from `wait`. It can't even throw an exception from `wait_for` without first acquiring the mutex.

Since it can't get out of its wait, there's no way it can get back onto the list of waiters before the second `notify_one` is called.

So, your code unblocks up to two threads blocked on the condvar, if there are that many. If there are fewer then the additional notifications have no effect.

Comment: Sorry. It looks like my question was too unclear. I've rephrased it and asked again here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085823/stdcondition-variablenotify-one-called-several-times-without-context-switc)